# Obter todo mês o saldo do mês anterior dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Como é que eu faço para obter o mês anterior de forma dinâmica;**

Tenho as tables Entradas e Saídas. No meu relatório eu mostro o **Saldo do mês** (Entradas - Saídas), em seguida eu mostro o **saldo do mês anterior**, isso funciona até 2 meses, no terceiro mês a soma fica errada! O que eu quero é que todo mês ele pegue o saldo anterior!

```
$entradas = Entradas::whereIn('entrada.cliente_id',$cliente_id)->whereBetween('dtarecebimento', [$dt_inicio, $dt_fim])->get();

$saida = Saida::whereIn('saida.cliente_id',$cliente_id)->whereBetween('dtarecebimento', [$dt_inicio, $dt_fim])->get();
```

**Saldo do mês** `$totalEntradas = $entradas - $saida;`

```
$dataIniAnterior = Carbon::parse($dt_inicio)->subMonth(1)->format('Y-m-d');
$dataFimAnterior = Carbon::parse($dt_fim)->subMonth(1)->format('Y-m-d');

$entradasAnterior = Entradas::whereBetween('dtarecebimento', [$dataIniAnterior, $dataFimAnterior])->get();
$saidasAnterior = Saida::whereBetween('data', [$dataIniAnterior, $dataFimAnterior])->get();
```

**Saldo do mês Anterior**

```
$entradaMesAnterior = $entradasAnterior - $saidasAnterior;
```

Comment: Pq você não utiliza a query para trazer essa informação direto do banco de dados e agrupado por mes?

Comment: Problema resolvido ...